# move in batch doesn't process subfolders

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, move

In the folder 15_Testdata I have a lot of subfolders with files. As you can see in my script in every subfolder I want to create master folder and move all the content from respective subfolder `%%~A\*.*` to respective Master folder `%%~A\MASTER\` . The problem is that with move command I can move only the files, but if there are folders on the same hierarchy level with files they aren't  moved. What can cause this behaviour?

```
FOR /d %%A IN (Z:\15_Testdata\*.*)  DO (
     mkdir %%~A\MASTER & move /y %%~A\*.* %%~A\MASTER\ 
)
```

Comment: You would need to use ROBOCOPY to mirror the existing folder structure.  Robocopy allows you to do the copy as an actual move instead of a copy as well.  So all you really need is to use ROBOCOPY.  You don't need the FOR command at all.

Comment: @Squashman I've replaced move with robocopy.exe %%~A %%~A\MASTER\ /move, but result is the same. Folder on the hierarchy wasn't copied.

Comment: Did you bother to read all the other options of `ROBOCOPY`. The very first two options listed in the `ROBOCOPY` help, look very promising.

Comment: Just tried every possible parameter, but it's still the same. robocopy /Move is the most appropriate one, but it doesn't move the folders. Maybe it's due to the for loop where I'm iterating only files in subfolders. But I can't do what I want without this loop